# Map function output type dynamically according to function parameter type

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

```js
// Provided input
const input: Input = {
  hello: {
    type: "string",
  },
  first: {
    second: {
      type: "number"
    }
  }
}

// Expected output
const output = {
  hello: "some-string",
  first: {
    second: 42
  }
}

// Function that processes the input and spits out the expected output
function processInput<T extends Input>(input: T): Output<T> {
  // Some logic
}
```

I want to process the nested `input` object using the `processInput` function to generate an output that looks like the `output` object. This can be simply done by checking if the `type` property exists, etc.

But my problem is the writing a type Output for the output. I would like to precisely type the output according the the provided input.

This is what I came up with so far:

```js
export type Property = { type: "string" } | { type: "number" };
export type Input = { [key: string]: Property | Input };

export type Output<T extends Input> = {
  [Key in keyof T]:
    T[Key] extends { type: "string" } ? string :
    T[Key] extends { type: "number" } ? number :
    T[Key] extends Input ? Output<T[Key]> :
    never
};
```

When accessing the `hello` property (for example, `output.hello`), it's always of type `never`. What's going wrong?

Comment: You just need to overload your function. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/w1pdyW). Let me know if it is smth what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is dynamic, this is impossible.

TypeScript only runs at compile-time, so it can't infer which properties a dynamic object has, because that information doesn't exist yet.

If the object is static (unlikely in actually useful code), you can use captain-yossarian from Ukraine's solution:

```js
export type Property = { type: "string" } | { type: "number" };
export type Input = { [key: string]: Property | Input };

export type Output<T extends Input> = {
  [Key in keyof T]:
  T[Key] extends { type: "string" } ? string :
  T[Key] extends { type: "number" } ? number :
  T[Key] extends Input ? Output<T[Key]> :
  never
};

function processInput<T extends Input>(input: T): Output<T>
function processInput<T extends Input>(input: T) {
  return null as any
}

const result = processInput({
  hello: {
    type: "string",
  },
  first: {
    second: {
      type: "number"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Awsome. That solved my problem. I really have to look deeper into overloading. Thanks a lot!